# Overlay div via jquery is set up successfully but not removed on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one simple jquery script which triggers on click on button and create another div overlays on current html,i got success creating the div but the problem is when i try to close the div by a button which i have created at setting up overlay div is not working what can be the possible cause? the code is as under

input#btn cause the div to diplay and its working fine.

1. Jquery function file

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('input#btn').click(function(){
       var attr = $('#div').css('display');
       alert(attr);
       if(attr == 'none')
       {
           $('#div').css('display','block');
           $('#div').html('<H1>PALAK MEVADA</H1><input id="close" type="button" value="CLOSE"/>');
       }
       return false;
   });

   $('input#close').click(function(){

       var attr = $('#div').css('display');
       alert(attr);
       if(attr == 'block')
       {
           $('#div').css('display','none');
           $('#div').html('');
       }
       return false;
   });
   });
   ```

Comment: If you're already using jQuery, try using .show() and .hide() instead of changing the CSS display attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**:

```
$(document).on('click','input#close',function(){
var attr = $('#div').css('display');
alert(attr);
if(attr == 'block')
{
    $('#div').css('display','none');
    $('#div').html('');
}
return false;
});
```

Comment: it works after adding jquery.js and myjs.js files inside my html("<script>....</script>") method!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The button doesn't exist when your code is first initialized, so your `$('input#close').click();` isn't bound to anything.

Try this:

```
$('input#close').on('click', function(){
 // Your code here...
});
```

Comment: it works after adding jquery.js and myjs.js files inside my html("<script>....</script>") method!!!!